# Are Flameskulls resistant to magical piercing damage?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, damage-resistance, damage-types

Most creatures in D&D 5e have specifics on what attacks or weapon damage types they are resistant to. For example:

> **Damage Resistances:** Bludgeoning, Piercing, and Slashing From Nonmagical Attacks

However, the description of the [Flameskull](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/flameskull) entails resistance to piercing damange without the phrase "From Nonmagical Weapons/Attacks":

> **Damage Resistances:** lightning, necrotic, piercing
>
> —**Flameskull**, Monster Manual, pg. 134

Wouldn't that mean the Flameskull is resistant to magical piercing damage as well as non-magical piercing damage?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

## It is resistant to all piercing

As you've noted in the [flameskull](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/flameskull), they are resistant to:

> Lightning, Necrotic, Piercing

Because there is no qualifier for only piercing from a non-magical source, it is resistant to any piercing damage.

Better bludgeon or slash it. Just don't use cold, fire, or poison - it's completely immune to those.